# Is there any information about how Alphas would have continued had it not been cancelled?

Tags: tv, alphas

The TV show "Alphas" was cancelled before a third season could be created. However, the second season ends on a pretty big cliffhanger:

> The main villain of the series having partially succeeded in enacting his plan, and everyone in the train station (bar Gary) seemingly unconscious.

Is there any information available on how the show would have continued had it not been cancelled?

Comment: [Sheldon? Is that you?](http://bigbangtheory.wikia.com/wiki/Alphas)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Consider me extremely offended :p

Comment: Seems to be off topic.

Comment: @Robert From the tour of the site - "Ask about: Plot, character, or setting explanations... Behind-the-scenes and fandom information".

My question could be counted as either an explanation of the plot (albeit the progression of the plot that hasn't happened yet) or behind-the-scenes information (being as it ended in a cliff-hanger, there must have been a plan going forward that producers/writers of the show would have know about).

Comment: I think it's on topic too. It's a pretty OK question, even if it's about an episode that happened to be not broadcast.

Comment: [I’ve tweeted the credited writer of the last episode of season 2.](https://twitter.com/pauldwaite/status/565538134394679296) [Hopefully I didn’t sound angry.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BbkU6jCNzw) (I realise I am pretty close to becoming Sheldon myself at this point.)

Comment: Advise to move the second sentence into the spoiler.  To anyone reading who has not seen season 2, this sentence could be a partial spoiler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While we'll probably never get anything official, the show's creator Zak Penn sent out a series of tweets containing the following highlights of what *could* have happened in Season 3:

http://www.summer-glau.com/blog/zak_penn_drops_alphas_season_3_hints/2013-03-09-738

> - Dr. Rosen lived. Hicks and Nina ended up together. Rachel went back to civilian life. Bill's kid was an alpha.
> - Gary ends up the leader of a reconstituted, less violent Red Flag. Parish dies of a viral infection that targets his peculiar chemistry.
> - Rosen ends up getting back together with his ex wife. They move to Binghamton, NY, where he gets tenure in the psychology dept.
> - Alpha abilities continue to evolve. The next generation can communicate with each other through non traditional means. It turns
>     out that they are heading towards a communal, hive like consciousness.
>     It has its pluses and minuses. Gary can't stand it.
> - Nothing wraps up too neatly. Being an alpha ends up neither blessing nor curse, simply different.
> - Hicks and Nina's kids are really good looking but a handful. Hicks falls off the wagon a few times. Nina pushes him back on.
> - Zooey [Zoe?] emancipates at age 12. Skyler [Skylar?] disappears one day and is never seen again. Dr. Rosen figures out the mechanism
>     behind Kats memory. She gains a long term memory, but loses her alpha
>     ability. Ill equipped to deal with normal life, hers ends tragically.
> - Zooey becomes a Senator, with help from Rosen. Later she turns on her own kind.
> - Rachel dumps John, ends up marrying an Orthodox Jew named Barry Shapiro. He is quiet and smart and clean. Rachel cheats on him a few
>     times
> - Bill starts meditating and goes back to the FBI.
> - Hicks's brother in law clears up his gambling debts. Cley gets a job as a high powered lawyer/lobbyist for a big energy company.
> - A guy named Barry Shump assassinates Gary Bell at a rally. Gary is 47 years old.
> - Bill and Rosen stay in touch. Rosen helps Bill with his alpha kids.
> - Gary accomplishes a great deal in his life. "Bellism" is coined to refer to underestimating people because of their neural differences.
> - Gary never does settle down, and he resents it when people suggest that he needs to be in love. That's their opinion.
> - An alpha named Mike Werbe ends up inventing a form of zip up one piece clothing that makes him a billionaire.
> - Dr. Rosen dyes his beard blue in solidarity with an alpha who is extradited to South America. (An all alpha country exists there.)
> - Also, to clarify, Hicks' brother in law is from his first wife. He has serious gambling debts.

There is still an active movement to get the third season done, so who knows?

Comment: A few of these looks like they may be jokes to me, but some of it could be true. Here's to hoping for a season 3 one day!

Comment: Do Mike Werbe's clothes have a colored stripe down one sleeve?